# How to detect dead codes in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I met a dead code in dart_Flutter and the reason was I tried to put both 'return' and 'print' statements together. How can a code become a dead code in Dart? What are the other common reasons and how can I detect dead codes in Dart?

Comment: *"and how can I detect dead codes in Dart?"* - see https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#individual-rules - a rule is named `dead_code`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use [error_lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens) extension in VS code or Android Studio. It will provide you warning/info/errors inline.

Answer (score 0):

Dead code means it'll never be executed. If you have a `return` statement before your `print()` call, the print call will never be run because the function already has returned a value and won't continue executing anything beyond that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Other than the 'return' and 'print' contradiction what can be caused to a dead code?

Comment: it's not a contradiction, it's just that anything that comes after a return statement will not be run (therefore making it dead code).